# Java card purchase query

Tags: android, global, javacard

I want to develop a android application in which i have to use java card.

Which development kit i have to buy for ??
I want to buy  java card , which implement Java Card 2.1.1 specifications and GlobalPlatform
Card Specification version 2.1  .

Is there a web site form where i can purchase??

I want a card reader also to test the apps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the Java Card Development Kit here:

http://java.sun.com/javacard/devkit/index.jsp

Card Readers can be fouind easily using Google:

http://www.google.fr/#sclient=psy&hl=fr&q=java+card+reader&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=d30d707248118335

The HP Smart Card Reader seems a good catch to me:

[http://www.amazon.com/HP-Smart-Card-Reader-Java/dp/B000K1QL7U](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000K1QL7U)